# Grab results from one query and put it in another (searching mx records)

Tags: python, linux, grep, mx-record

I have a lot of email log files to go through. I'm trying to find everyone we send to, sorted by mx server.

This will return a list of the MX servers:

```
grep 'mx' /my/log/file | cut -d , -f 11 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort | uniq
```

Ex output:

```
mx3.hotmail.com
mx2.hotmail.com
mx1.hotmail.com
mx4.hotmail.com
```

This grabs the domains that are sent to from that MX server (in this case, all of hotmails):

```
grep 'mx*.hotmail.com' /my/log/file | cut -d , -f 6 | cut -d '@' -f 2 | sort | uniq
```

Ex output:

```
hotmail.com
hotmail.com.au
```

How can I script this so that I can plug the results from one query straight into the other? I put python as a tag because I'm familiar with it.

Comment: show sample log entries.

Answer (score 0):

`mx*.hotmail.com` should match *m.hotmail.com*, *mx.hotmail.com*, *mxx.hotmail.com*, etc. You probably want `mx.*\.hotmail\.com`

To use a string from one bash command in another, you can use `$()`. E.g. `echo abc$(echo def)ghi`

You can also use backquotes, but backquotes don't nest as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we ended up doing:

```
cat /my/log/file | cut -d "," -f 11,6 | cut -d '@' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | egrep '(([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}),(([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})' | cut -d "," -f 2,1 | sort | uniq > /tmp/mxservers2.txt
```

The result looks like this:

```
hotmail.com,mx1.hotmail.com
```

For reference, the log entries look like this:

```
d,2012-07-17 07:09:29+0000,2012-07-17 07:09:15+0000,,bounce@address.net,recipient@example.net,,relayed,2.0.0 (success),smtp;250 2.0.0 bK9F1j04M0vJLGl06K9VnA mail accepted for delivery,mx.example.net (0.0.0.0),,smtp,(127.0.0.1),smtp,sending IP,receiving IP,"ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES,8BITMIME,SIZE,STARTTLS",18704,sending.domain.com,message.streaming,,FALSE,=?utf-8?Q?Subject?= <sender@example2.net>
```

Not perfect, but got the job done.